# The entity type ... is not part of the model for the current context MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the following error message:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information:
>
> The entity type Admins is not part of the model for the current context.

My controller:

```
...
public void isAdmin( )
{
        Session["user"] = Environment.UserName;

        if (db.Admin.Where(a => a.Benutzer.Equals(Session["user")) != null)  
        {  
            Session["Login"] = true; 
        }
}
```

My Admins.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Admins
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Benutzer { get; set; }
}
```

My Context.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class NORMENEntities : DbContext
{
    public NORMENEntities() : base("name=NORMENEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Admins>().ToTable("Admin");
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    ...
    public virtual DbSet<Admins> Admin {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an Admin table in your Database? If so try changing `Admins` into `Admin` without an 's'

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Yes the Admin table is in my db

Comment: In this line: => if (db.Admin.Where(a => a.Benutzer.Equals(Session["user")) != null)

Comment: You need to tell the DbContext about your `Admin` table in the OnModelCreating method override. Why there is a code commented  //modelBuilder.Entity<Admins>().ToTable("Admin"); ? It was not working?

Comment: Yes, that was not working

Comment: Are you using EF Code First or Database First?

Comment: `Yes, that was not working` Define 'not working'.